# How to simulate correlated GARCH using rmgarch package in R

Tags: r, simulation, garch

I'd like to simulate a couple of simulated and correlated GARCH(1,1) using the R package `rmgarch`.

I tried to do:

```
spec = gogarchspec(mean.model = list(demean = "constant"),
               variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1), submodel = NULL),
               distribution.model = list(distribution = "manig"), ica = "fastica")
sim = gogarchsim(spec = spec)
```

But the `gogarchsim` function requires a fit object. If I want to simulate, why should I fit?

Comment: I think the author of the package decided to omit the functionality that you desire. The motivation might have been as follows. Fitted models may be considered more relevant in practice than theoretically specified models that do not stem from fitting. Fitted models stem from real data that analysts may want to forecast, and simulation is a helpful tool in that.

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Questions of the form *How to do something in R?* are off topic, but I will answer the other question in your post. If I am not mistaken, the author of the package decided to omit the functionality that you desire. The motivation might have been as follows. Fitted models may be considered more relevant in practice than theoretically specified models that do not stem from fitting. Fitted models stem from real data that analysts may want to forecast, and simulation is a helpful tool in that.